# Sql query for sorting from another table

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables 1st tbl_student and 2nd tbl_hobby

tbl_stundet's columns

- stdentid
- studentname

and tbl_hobby columns

- hobbyid
- hobby

I want to sort list of tbl_hobyy by studentname ??

Comment: Do you have stdentid as a **FOREIGN KEY** in the TABLE tbl_hobby_columns

Comment: Yes i h studentid as foreignkey in tbl_hobby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the tables together and the table tbl_hobby must have a column "stundetid" as a foreign key references to the primary key of tbl_stundet "uid"

```
Select * from tbl_stundet INNER JOIN tbl_hobby on(tbl_stundet.uid = tbl_hobby.stundetid) order by studentname ASC
```

Comment: Is there any mentioned COLUMN stundetid in the table tbl_hobby (do not assume, so that the visitors/users do not get confused while searching for answers)

Comment: @MalikAsif thanks for your advice. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Its query is vry useful and this problem has been solved